# Questions about using forkpty to create pseudo terminal to ssh in C

Tags: c, linux

```
pid = forkpty (&pty,0,0,0);
if (pid == 0) {
    execl ("/usr/bin/ssh", "ssh", hostname, NULL);
    exit (0);
} else if (pid > 0) {
    ssh_pid = pid;
    ssh_pty = pty;
    if(child_ssh_success()) {
        get_user_input();
        send_user_input_to_child_ssh_and_child_forword_it_to_remote_server();
        get_remote_server_response_from_child();
        display_response_to_stdout();
    }
}
```

How can I tell whether `ssh` success or not?

How can parent know that child has successfully `ssh-ed` to remote server, so parent can send something to remote server?

Comment: Just a side-note: do not expect to be able to "send" a password to ssh via that fd you net. Openssh opens /dev/tty and directly reads from there. You did not ask this but I though I might share it.

Comment: Why??This is what I'm doing...

Comment: Security. An attacker could emulate a terminal the way you're doing here and log all the passwords entered. Maybe look into using key based authentication for ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `waitpid` in the parent ( ie inside your `else if ( pid>0)` condition ) to get the status of the child

```
#include   <sys/wait.h>
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *stat_loc, int options);
```

Quoting [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_waitpid.html)

**stat_loc**

> A pointer to an integer where the wait function will return the status
>   of the child process. If the waitpid function returns because a
>   process has exited, the return value is equal to the pid of the
>   exiting process. For this, if the value of stat_loc is not NULL,
>   information is stored in the location pointed to by stat_loc. **If
>   status is returned from a terminated child process that returned a
>   value of 0, the value stored at the location pointed to by stat_loc is
>   0.** If the return is greater than 0, you can evaluate this information using the following macros: WEXITSTATUS WIFEXITED WIFSIGNALED
>   WTERMSIG.

So if `stat_loc` is zero, you *may* assume that SSH terminated normally

**EDIT1**

If you dont want the parent to be blocked, then you need to set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and do the same `waitpid` there. This time as the child has already terminated, `waitpid` will return immediately

Something on these lines

```
pid_t pid;
int main ()
{
struct sigaction action;

memset (&action, 0, sizeof(action));
action.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;

if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, 0)) 
    {
    perror ("sigaction");
    return 1;
}

pid = forkpty (&pty,0,0,0);
if (pid == 0) 
{
    execl ("/usr/bin/ssh", "ssh", hostname, NULL);
    exit (0);
} 
else if (pid > 0) 
{
    ssh_pid = pid;
    ssh_pty = pty;
}
}

/* SIGCHLD handler. */
static void sigchld_handler (int sig)
{
    int chld_state;

    while (waitpid(pid,&child_state,options) > 0) 
    {
       if (WIFEXITED(chld_state)) 
       {
           printf("Child exited with RC=%d\n",WEXITSTATUS(chld_state));
       }
    }

}
```

Make `pid` global so that you can access it from `sigchld_handler` too. Generally `ssh` returns `0` for SUCCESS and `255` ( or some other positive value ) for failure, though I am not cent percent sure on this.

**EDIT2**

From our discussion, I see you want to execute commands as well on the remote server. I suggest you run `ssh` this

```
ssh root@remoteserver.com 'ls -l'
```

You can pass these arguments of `ssh` via `execl()` and as explained in **EDIT1**, you can check for its return value to verify whether everything went fine. Also, since you are doing `ssh` from code, you may not want to enter password manually. Here is how you do [password less login](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/)

Comment: How can I tell `ssh` is success? Parent should not be blocked.

Comment: @everbox I edited my answer to address your queries. Do check out!

Comment: Thank you. Now I know how to tell `ssh` failed. But how can I know that child has successfully `ssh-ed `to remote server, so I can send command to remote server, and receive from it?

Comment: What kinds of commands you want to execute on the server? And what you mean by "receive from it"?

Comment: Thanks for your kind and patience answer, sorry for my poor English. I have re-edited my post.